# What type of antenna connector is this? (USB 4G modem)

Tags: connector, antenna, lte, 4g

[image]

What type of antenna connector is in the Huawei E5573Cs-322 phone? (Internally - left side on the image) SMA or ts-9?

Photo attached.

Comment: Looks more like U.Fl or MHF4. What's the outer diameter?

Answer (score 1):

> SMA or ts-9?

Neither: Neither of those is a [cable-to-board interior RF connector](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=cable_to_board_rf_conn). Your connector is a cable-to-board interior RF connector.

That picture is out of focus, and you didn't give us its dimensions, so I can't bee too precise, but it appears to be a female. If so, my [Identiconn utility](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=cable_to_board_rf_conn&&fl=00000000000000000000300020000000-c-%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C) lists these possibilities:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- [*Industry standard*](https://www.hirose.com/product/series/MS-156C) - [MS-156C](https://www.hirose.com/product/document?clcode=CL0358-0188-8-00&productname=MS-156R-HRMJ-1&series=MS-156C&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=D49421_en) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.se/short/4tvtd5)
- [*Industry standard*](https://www.murata.com/en-us/products/connector/switchconnector/swg) - [SWG](https://www.murata.com/-/media/webrenewal/support/library/catalog/products/switch/switch/o30e.ashx) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.se/short/4t0mz0)
- Hirose - [MS-145](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Hirose%20PDFs/MS-145.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.se/short/4tvpd1)
- [Hirose](https://www.hirose.com/product/series/MS-147) - [MS-147](https://www.hirose.com/en/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=MS-147&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=D49712_en) (pdf)
- [Hirose](https://www.hirose.com/product/series/MS-162B) - [MS-162](https://www.hirose.com/en/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=MS-162B&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=D49422_en) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.se/short/4tvctj)
- Hirose - [MS-166](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Hirose%20PDFs/MS-166_Series.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.se/short/4tvphh)
- [Hirose](https://www.hirose.com/product/series/MS-180) - [MS-180](https://www.hirose.com/en/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=MS-180&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=D31614_en) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.se/short/4tvp4h)
- [I-pex](https://www.i-pex.com/product/mhf-sw23) - [MHF-SW23](https://www.i-pex.com/sites/default/files/downloads/pdf/2D_MHF-SW23_20549C9.pdf) (pdf)
- [Murata](https://www.murata.com/en-us/products/connector/switchconnector/swd) - [SWD](https://www.murata.com/-/media/webrenewal/support/library/catalog/products/switch/switch/o30e.ashx) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.se/short/4tnpp1)
- [Murata](https://www.murata.com/en-us/products/connector/switchconnector/swf) - [SWF](https://www.murata.com/-/media/webrenewal/support/library/catalog/products/switch/switch/o30e.ashx) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.se/short/4tnpzz)
- [Murata](https://www.murata.com/en-us/products/connector/switchconnector/swh) - [SWH](https://www.murata.com/-/media/webrenewal/support/library/catalog/products/switch/switch/o30e.ashx) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.se/short/4tnpz9)
- [Murata](https://www.murata.com/en-us/products/connector/switchconnector/swj) - [SWJ](https://www.murata.com/-/media/webrenewal/support/library/catalog/products/switch/switch/o30e.ashx) (pdf)
- Rosenberger - [FMC](https://www.rosenberger.com/0_documents/de/catalogs/ba_communication/catalog_coax/03_Chapter_FMC.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.se/short/4tnjh8)

If you tell us the dimensions, we can narrow it down:

1. The outer diameter
2. The height above the PCB